# Java Jersey Webservice on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, services

As I read that the JVM for Raspberry Pi performs well enough to use the Pi as an application server. https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/comparing_jvms_on_arm_linux

I would like to know if it is possible to run an ordinary Jersey Webservice with a Raspberry Pi? If yes, it will require a different archetype? Which modifications I would need to make on a project which I'm used to run on Glassfish 4?

Comment: I've removed your secondary question about the Arduino since it is tangential and depends on *how* you want to communicate physically with the Arduino -- I would guess UART is the most common option, but there is a long array of possibilities (e.g., if you equip an Arduino with a bluetooth module, you could use that, etc.).  You will have to research and ask about those issues separately, and the question WRT to Java then becomes something more generic, such as "How can I communicate via UART with Java?".

Comment: Did you google [jersey webservice rpi](https://blogs.oracle.com/javatraining/entry/using_device_i_o_with)?